# Unable to drag and drop an element under <li> to <td> using selenium Actions class methods

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate a use case where I should be able to drag an element which is enclosed by "ul>li" element to a target location, which is a "td" element under a table. My code is as below

```
WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='items']/ul/li[1]");
WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='cart']/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[3]");

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.clickAndHold(source)
   .moveToElement(target)
   .release(target)
   .build()
       .perform();
```

I have also tried pausing between each step, by adding

```
actions.moveToElement(source)
.pause(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
.clickAndHold(source)
.pause(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
.moveByOffset(1,0)
.moveToElement(target)
.moveByOffset(1, 0)
.pause(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
.release()
.pause(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
    .build()
    .perform();
```

While running in debug mode, I do see that clickAndHold is being performed, as I see the element highlighted. But the moment next action is being performed, I do not see the element dragged to the target nor released.

I'm not sure, if the issue is with the locator or the actions code.

I noticed the same behavior, if I used actions.dragAndDrop(source,target);

To simulate this, I tried to execute similar code against http://jqueryui.com/droppable/ and it is working fine. My code against this website is as below

```
driver.get("http://www.jqueryui.com/droppable/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("demo-frame")));
WebElement drag = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='draggable']"));
WebElement drop = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='droppable']"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
//action.dragAndDrop(drag, drop).build().perform(); //This is working
action.clickAndHold(drag)
      .moveToElement(drop)
      .release(drop)
      .build()
      .perform();  // This is working
```

The only difference I noticed between this example and the former is, the position of the elements and how they are enclosed. In the former, the element to be dragged is under ul > li , and target location is a td element under a table.

Where as the example in jqueryui, is both are identified by id.

Also, I confirm that the xpaths used to identify the source and target in the former example are correct, as I can see them being highlighted when validated using Chrome developer tools.

Could you please suggest what can be done to fix this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the URL, if it's not private ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get("http://www.jqueryui.com/droppable/");
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("demo-frame")));
```

**//First, we capture the 1st element which we need to drag in variable "From."**

```
WebElement From = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='draggable']"));
```

**//Second, we capture the 2nd element on which we need to drop the 1st element in variable "To".**

```
WebElement To = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='droppable']"));
```

**//Third, we create object of Actions class as we use methods of Actions class.**

```
   Actions act=new Actions(driver);
   act.dragAndDrop(From, To).build().perform();
```

For drag and drop element we use dragAndDrop method of Actions class and passes the parameters as the first element(Sourcelocator) "From" and the second element(Destinationlocator) "To". Below line will drag the 1st element and drop it on the 2nd element.

Comment: This is exactly what I tried. As I mentioned I don't have problem implementing this mechanism against the droppable in jqueryui.  I have issues with another project of similar usecase.

Comment: The third option worked for me.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced like this issue, keep on trying different ways, this works for me:

```
Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(src).moveToElement(trg).release(trg).build(); 
dragAndDrop.perform();
Thread.sleep(3000);
new Actions(oWebDriver).moveToElement(src).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(3000);
new Actions(oWebDriver).moveToElement(trg).click().build().perform();
```